# FreeBSD 10 unable to boot ZFS pool - "unknown file system"

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I have a server with FreeBSD 10.3 that I am suddenly unable to reboot. The server has been working fine for over 6 months but it not rebooted it since about 5 months ago, until now. I end up in "mountroot" with the `unknown file system` error.

When I boot into "Rescue" (the server is on Hetzner.de and also has a KVM) I am able to mount the entire pool with the command: `zpool import -o altroot=/mnt zroot` . It seems that the pool is fine.

All commands below are run from the Rescue after the zpool import:

```
[root@rescue /mnt]# cat /mnt/boot/loader.conf
kern.geom.label.gptid.enable="0"
zfs_load="YES"
vfs.root.mountfrom="zfs:zroot/ROOT/default"

[root@rescue /mnt/boot]# mount
zroot/ROOT/default on /mnt (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/tmp on /mnt/tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/home on /mnt/usr/home (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/ports on /mnt/usr/ports (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/src on /mnt/usr/src (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/audit on /mnt/var/audit (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/crash on /mnt/var/crash (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/log on /mnt/var/log (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/mail on /mnt/var/mail (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/tmp on /mnt/var/tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot on /mnt/zroot (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)

[root@rescue /mnt]# cat /mnt/etc/rc.conf
hostname="stream"
keymap="swedish.iso.kbd"
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
ifconfig_em0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
sshd_enable="YES"
powerd_enable="YES"
# Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
dumpdev="AUTO"
zfs_enable="YES"
lighttpd_enable=YES
```

The pool:

```
[root@rescue /mnt]# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
zroot  8.12T  5.71T  2.42T         -    23%    70%  1.00x  ONLINE  /mnt

[root@rescue ~]# zfs list -o name,canmount,mountpoint -r zroot/ROOT
NAME                CANMOUNT  MOUNTPOINT
zroot/ROOT                on  none
zroot/ROOT/default        on  /mnt

[root@rescue /mnt]# gpart show
=>         34  17578327997  mfid0  GPT  (8.2T)
           34            6         - free -  (3.0K)
           40         1024      1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
         1064          984         - free -  (492K)
         2048      4194304      2  freebsd-swap  (2.0G)
      4196352  17574129664      3  freebsd-zfs  (8.2T)
  17578326016         2015         - free -  (1.0M)


[root@rescue /mnt/boot]# zfs list
NAME                 USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zroot               5.71T  2.16T    96K  /mnt/zroot
zroot/ROOT          5.71T  2.16T    96K  none
zroot/ROOT/default  5.71T  2.16T  5.71T  /mnt
zroot/tmp            112K  2.16T   112K  /mnt/tmp
zroot/usr            688M  2.16T    96K  /mnt/usr
zroot/usr/home      5.51M  2.16T  5.51M  /mnt/usr/home
zroot/usr/ports      682M  2.16T   682M  /mnt/usr/ports
zroot/usr/src         96K  2.16T    96K  /mnt/usr/src
zroot/var           5.91M  2.16T    96K  /mnt/var
zroot/var/audit       96K  2.16T    96K  /mnt/var/audit
zroot/var/crash       96K  2.16T    96K  /mnt/var/crash
zroot/var/log        520K  2.16T   520K  /mnt/var/log
zroot/var/mail      5.03M  2.16T  5.03M  /mnt/var/mail
zroot/var/tmp         96K  2.16T    96K  /mnt/var/tmp
```

[FreeBSD 10 won't boot to ZFS root after power failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/616991/freebsd-10-wont-boot-to-zfs-root-after-power-failure) is similar to this issue but his pool is much larger than mine and I do not see that the errors he got. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: We managed to solve the problem by creating a small boot pool of swap partition and boot from it. It seems that the problem was because of the huge boot pool. Boot block can't cope with a pool that big and reads only part of it, saying that it is inconsistent. It worked previously when the pool was not filled so much.

Comment: Does `zfs` module get loaded on boot?

Comment: How can I check that? I checked dmesg and it says the following during boot:
`ZFS filesystem version: 5` and 
`ZFS storage pool version: features support (5000)`